# Spring Boot 2 datasource by configuration does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, datasource, camunda

I have an application.yml(!) for the configuration containing the following:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:h2:file:./camunda-h2-database"
    driverClassName: "org.h2.Driver"
    username: "sa"
    password: ""
```

Which gives me the errormessage:

```
2021-03-11T17:02:48,600 WARN  [main] o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.CamundaBpmAutoConfiguration$ProcessEngineConfigurationImplDependingConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'processEngineConfigurationImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfigurationImpl' defined in class path resource [org/camunda/bpm/spring/boot/starter/CamundaBpmConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'processEngineConfigurationImpl' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'camundaDatasourceConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Doing it this way works:

```java
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:file:./camunda-h2-database");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}
```

Ideas? :-)

Comment: Make sure that you don't exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` in your code. Smth like this `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [DataSourceAutoConfiguration::class])`

Comment: And also try to rename `driverClassName` to `driver-class-name` in your application.yml

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko, your second comment solved my problem. Please add it as an answer so that I can select it as "the solution" (just add both ideas). THX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename `driverClassName` to `driver-class-name` since Kebab case is preferred over Camel case in Spring Boot Auto Configuration properties.

If that doesn't help then make sure that you didn't turn off `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` feature. It usually may look like

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [DataSourceAutoConfiguration::class])
public class BootApplication { ... }
```